# "valid deviance" is nan for GBM model, What does this means and how to get rid of this?

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost, gbm, boosting

I am using Gradient boosting for classification. Though the result is improving but I am getting NaN in validdeviance.

```
Model = gbm.fit(
  x= x_Train ,
  y = y_Train ,
  distribution = "bernoulli",
  n.trees = GBM_NTREES ,
  shrinkage = GBM_SHRINKAGE ,
  interaction.depth = GBM_DEPTH ,
  n.minobsinnode = GBM_MINOBS ,
  verbose = TRUE
  )
```

Result

[image]

How to tune the parameter to get the validdeviance.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, strangely, we're few on this one ...

Adding `train.fraction = 0.5` to the option list solves the issue (it seems there is no default value, and validdeviance is not computed without the train.fraction value explicitly mentioned).